# create word document with html content in c#

Tags: c#, html, ms-word, document

I want to create a word document with html content in c#. But the following code shows the content as a text only not html formating...

Here is my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();  
              app.Visible=true;

              object template = Missing.Value;
              object newTemplate = Missing.Value;
              object documentType = Missing.Value;
              object visible = true;  //Show the doc while we work.
              _Document doc = app.Documents.Add(ref template,
                       ref newTemplate,
                       ref documentType,
                       ref visible);   
            doc.Words.First.InsertBefore ("<html><body>HTML content here!</body></html>");
```

Comment: Why would Word think it is HTML ? What is you wanted to show `<p>` ?

Comment: Actually I will put some tables as the word content and I am using html to format the body. This part "<html><body>HTML content here!</body></html>" is only example..

Comment: I think there must be a property to specify the content type is html but I could not find it.

Answer (score 3):

You might use a HTML file as the source:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        var file = new FileInfo("input.html");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app 
            = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        try
        {
            app.Visible = true;
            object missing = Missing.Value;
            object visible = true;
            _Document doc = app.Documents.Add(ref missing,
                     ref missing,
                     ref missing,
                     ref visible);
            var bookMark = doc.Words.First.Bookmarks.Add("entry");
            bookMark.Range.InsertFile(file.FullName);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            app.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doc.Words.First.Bookmarks.Add("entry"); this part gives error?
You say that, I must write the content to a file then read?

Comment: Adding the HTML to a file and then inserting the file into the word document worked for me.